# Boxplot stratified by column in python pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, boxplot

I would like to draw a boxplot for the following pandas dataframe:

```
> p1.head(10)

   N0_YLDF    MAT
0     1.29  13.67
1     2.32  10.67
2     6.24  11.29
3     5.34  21.29
4     6.35  41.67
5     5.35  91.67
6     9.32  21.52
7     6.32  31.52
8     3.33  13.52
9     4.56  44.52
```

I want the boxplots to be of the column 'N0_YLDF', but they should be stratified by 'MAT'. When I use the foll. command:

```
p1.boxplot(column='N0_YLDF',by='MAT')
```

It uses all the unique MAT values, which in the full p1 dataframe number around 15,000. This results in an incomprehensible boxplot.

Is there any way I can stratify the MAT values, so that I get a different boxplot of N0_YLDF for the first quartile of MAT values and so on....

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pandas.qcut` will give you the quantiles, but a histogram-like operation will require some `numpy` trickery which comes in handy here:

```
_, breaks = np.histogram(df.MAT, bins=5)
ax = df.boxplot(column='N0_YLDF', by='Class')
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['%s'%val for i, val in enumerate(breaks) if i in df.Class])
```

[image]

The dataframe now looks like this:

```
   N0_YLDF    MAT  Class
0     1.29  13.67      1
1     2.32  10.67      0
2     6.24  11.29      1
3     5.34  21.29      1
4     6.35  41.67      2
5     5.35  91.67      5
6     9.32  21.52      1
7     6.32  31.52      2
8     3.33  13.52      1
9     4.56  44.52      3

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

It can also be used to get the quartile plot:

```
breaks = np.asarray(np.percentile(df.MAT, [25,50,75,100]))
df['Class'] = (df.MAT.values > breaks[..., np.newaxis]).sum(0)
ax = df.boxplot(column='N0_YLDF', by='Class')
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['%s'%val for val in breaks])
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you so much again! Is there any way you can replace the x-axis labels by the actual MAT quantile value?

Comment: That's easy, you can just use the values of `breaks`, if the plot is returned as `ax`: add this `ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['%s'%val for i, val in enumerate(breaks) if i in df.Class])`, the `breaks` contains the bin edges of the histogram.

Comment: thanks for the further edits. I am trying to change the color of the boxes in the boxplot using pyplot.setp(ax['boxes'], color='blue'). however I get the error ''AxesSubplot' object is unsubscriptable'. Any idea on how to avoid this error? thanks!

Comment: Ah, I found this reply of yours (@ CT Zhu) for the boxplot styling. that works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453994/styling-of-pandas-groupby-boxplots

Comment: Happy to hear that. Sometimes I even find my own answers. Happy coding!

Answer (score 10):

Pandas has the `cut` and `qcut` functions to make stratifying variables like this easy:

```
# Just asking for split into 4 equal groups (i.e. quartiles) here,
# but you can split on custom quantiles by passing in an array
p1['MAT_quartiles'] = pd.qcut(p1['MAT'], 4, labels=['0-25%', '25-50%', '50-75%', '75-100%'])
p1.boxplot(column='N0_YLDF', by='MAT_quartiles')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Marius want to do a pull request to add this to cookbook.rst? pls do it inline so the figure shows with the code as well - include a link to this question as well - thanks

Comment: @Jeff: Sure, I'll try to get round to it tonight. I've been meaning to see if there were any useful contributions I could add to pandas, this looks like a good place to start.

Comment: great! FYI wanted to put more of the cookbook examples inline (they r mostly links now), so that would be extremely helpful if u have some time!