# pandas - boxplot median color settings issues

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm running Pandas 0.16.2 and Matplotlib 1.4.3. I have this issue coloring the median of the boxplot generated by the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

medianprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=2, color='blue')

bp = df.boxplot(medianprops=medianprops)

plt.show()
```

That returns:

[image]

It appears that the `color` setting is not read. Changing only the settings of linestyle and linewidth the plot reacts correctly.

```
medianprops = dict(linestyle='-.', linewidth=5, color='blue')
```

[image]

Anyone can reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the following workaround works well, returning a `dict` from the boxplot command:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bp = df.boxplot(return_type='dict')
```

and then assign directly colors and linewidth to the medians with:

```
[[item.set_color('r') for item in bp[key]['medians']] for key in bp.keys()]
[[item.set_linewidth(0.8) for item in bp[key]['medians']] for key in bp.keys()]
```

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the code for `DataFrame.boxplot()` there is some special code to handle the colors of the different elements that supersedes the `kws` passed to matplotlib's `boxplot`. In theory, there seem to be a way to pass a `color=` argument containing a dictionary with keys being `'boxes', 'whiskers', 'medians', 'caps'` but I can't seem to get it to work when calling `boxplot()` directly.

However, this seem to work:

```
df.plot(kind='box', color={'medians': 'blue'}, 
        medianprops={'linestyle': '--', 'linewidth': 5})
```

see [Pandas Boxplot Examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#box-plots)

Comment: Thanks, but for my purposes in plotting a multindexed dataframe I need the boxplot function (with 'by' column) instead of the kind='box' version.

Comment: Actually using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28103385/2699288) answer it works!