# Make the median line of matplotlib boxplot invisible

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

By default, the median line of a matplotlib boxplot is red. How can I make it invisible, or how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This example uses a custom setting of `medianprops`: http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/boxplot_demo.html. Try using `linewidth=0` or `linestyle=None`.

How to set the linestyle is described here: http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle

This thread treats a similar topic: [pandas - boxplot median color settings issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502153/pandas-boxplot-median-color-settings-issues)

Comment: The pandas answer is a great resource for removing or enlarging the median line.  Good answer.

Comment: Using `linestyle=None` and `linewidth=0.` worked for me, using only one of the two did not.