# Change the facecolor of boxplot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot, colormap

I need to change the colors of the boxplot drawn using `pandas` utility function. I can change most properties using the `color` argument but can't figure out how to change the `facecolor` of the box. Someone knows how to do it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randn(100, 4)
labels = list("ABCD")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=labels)
props = dict(boxes="DarkGreen", whiskers="DarkOrange", medians="DarkBlue", caps="Gray")
df.plot.box(color=props)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While I still recommend seaborn and raw matplotlib over the plotting interface in pandas, it turns out that you can pass `patch_artist=True` as a kwarg to `df.plot.box`, which will pass it as a kwarg to `df.plot`, which will pass is as a kwarg to `matplotlib.Axes.boxplot`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randn(100, 4)
labels = list("ABCD")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=labels)
props = dict(boxes="DarkGreen", whiskers="DarkOrange", medians="DarkBlue", caps="Gray")
df.plot.box(color=props, patch_artist=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using `df.plot.box` with `patch_artist=True` and `return_type='both'` (which returns the matplotlib axes the boxplot is drawn on and a dictionary whose values are the matplotlib Lines of the boxplot) in order to have the best customization possibilities.

For example, given this data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.randn(100, 4), 
    columns=list("ABCD")
)
```

you can set a specific color for **all the boxes**:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6)) 
ax,props = df.plot.box(patch_artist=True, return_type='both', ax=ax)
for patch in props['boxes']:
    patch.set_facecolor('lime')
plt.show()
```

[image]

you can set a specific color for **each box**:

```
colors = ['green','blue','yellow','red']

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6)) 
ax,props = df.plot.box(patch_artist=True, return_type='both', ax=ax)
for patch,color in zip(props['boxes'],colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)
plt.show()
```

[image]

you can easily integrate a **colormap**:

```
colors = np.random.randint(0,10, 4)
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('rainbow')
colors_cm = [cm((c-colors.min())/(colors.max()-colors.min())) for c in colors]

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6)) 
ax,props = df.plot.box(patch_artist=True, return_type='both', ax=ax)
for patch,color in zip(props['boxes'],colors_cm):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)
# to add colorbar
fig.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(
    plt.cm.colors.Normalize(min(colors),max(colors)), 
    cmap='rainbow'
), ax=ax, cmap='rainbow')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, I ended up creating a function to plot this, using raw `matplotlib`.

```
def plot_boxplot(data, ax):
    bp = ax.boxplot(data.values, patch_artist=True)

    for box in bp['boxes']:
        box.set(color='DarkGreen')
        box.set(facecolor='DarkGreen')

    for whisker in bp['whiskers']:
        whisker.set(color="DarkOrange")

    for cap in bp['caps']:
        cap.set(color="Gray")

    for median in bp['medians']:
        median.set(color="white")

    ax.axhline(0, color="DarkBlue", linestyle=":")

    ax.set_xticklabels(data.columns)
```