# How can I set boxplot color by rainbow in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, colors, boxplot

I want to create boxplot of data in comparing, my plot looks like

[image: my]

how can I add color like

[image: rainbow]

Comment: using pandas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71940578/10375049

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can color the box following [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/boxplot_color_demo.html). Beyond that, you will need to map your data in mind to color on the "rainbow" colormap with [this module](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html). Here is an example with random test data. I map colors with means in this example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

# Random test data
test_data = [np.random.normal(mean, 1, 100) for mean in range(50)]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 16))

# Horizontal box plot
bplot = axes.boxplot(test_data,
                     vert=False,   # vertical box aligmnent
                     patch_artist=True)   # fill with color

# Fill with colors
cmap = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='rainbow')
test_mean = [np.mean(x) for x in test_data]
for patch, color in zip(bplot['boxes'], cmap.to_rgba(test_mean)):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, you beat me to the punch! Really nice approach, I wouldn't think of using `np.mean(x)` as a paramater, clever! (+1)

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar Thank you. OP didn't specify how to map the color. So I would say your answer is nice too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `cmap` property to actually be a function, accepting values between 0 and 1, and call it "normalising" your data. Using `matplotlib` example on boxplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Random test data
np.random.seed(123)
all_data = [np.random.normal(0, 5, 100) for std in range(1, 21)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, figsize=(9, 4))

# rectangular box plot
bplot = ax.boxplot(all_data, 0, '', 0, patch_artist=True) 

cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('rainbow')
colors = [cm(val/len(all_data)) for val in range(len(all_data))]

for patch, color in zip(bplot['boxes'], colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)

plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: i get only purple color for this code @ViníciusAguiar

Comment: That's weird, it should work, what do you get from printing `colors` ?