# Categorical axis labels instead of numbers for box plot?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I would like to generate a horizontal boxplot with cmap color filling of the boxes and I found this: [How can I set boxplot color by rainbow in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204651/how-can-i-set-boxplot-color-by-rainbow-in-matplotlib)

I modified the code so to include categories at index like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Random test data
test_data_df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(mean, 1, 10) for mean in range(10)])
index = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]
test_data_df.index = index

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))

# Horizontal box plot
bplot = axes.boxplot(test_data_df,
                     vert=False,   # vertical box aligmnent
                     patch_artist=True)   # fill with color

# Fill with colors
cmap = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='nipy_spectral')
test_mean = [np.mean(x) for x in test_data]
for patch, color in zip(bplot['boxes'], cmap.to_rgba(test_mean)):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)

plt.show()
```

[image]

How could I modify the code to use the index `["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]` as the y-axis label?

Thanks!

Comment: try this:`axes.set_yticklabels(index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you can `set_yticklabels` to your `index` list:

```py
axes.set_yticklabels(index)
```

[image: box plot with categorical axis labels]

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Btw, how did you remove the ticks on the y-axis? Could you show the codes you used? Thanks! :)

Comment: @JohnnyTam I just used your code, but I do have seaborn loaded, which silently modifies some stuff (even regular matplotlib plots). You can `import seaborn as sns; sns.set_style('white')` to get this styling applied to your matplotlib plots.