# Box plot for specific columns in dataframe, with different colour

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I am struggling to plot a boxplot for custom column names of dataframe and afterwards fill them with custom different colors.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,4,3],[3,4,3]],columns=['x','y','z'])
df.boxplot(column=['x', 'y'])
plt.show()
```

I can't customize colours of my boxplots. Is there any way how to do it with simple code?

Comment: See [change-the-facecolor-of-boxplot-in-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297093/change-the-facecolor-of-boxplot-in-pandas) for a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,4,3],[3,4,3]], columns=['x','y','z'])
box = plt.boxplot([df['x'], df['y']], patch_artist=True)
colors = ['blue', 'green']
for patch, color in zip(box['boxes'], colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)
plt.show()
```