# Plotting a boxplot using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a box plot using pandas.
The code for the same using seaborn is as follows:

sns.boxplot(y='Salary', data=eda)

[image: boxplot using seaborn]

and this is the code I use while using pandas:

boxplot = eda.boxplot(column=['Salary'])

[image: boxplot using pandas]

is there any way I could get the same box plot using pandas as I did while using seaborn?

Edit: I need the column 'salary' on the y-axis while using pandas
Thanks!

Comment: You need `eda.boxplot(..., patch_artist=True)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the facecolor of boxplot in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297093/change-the-facecolor-of-boxplot-in-pandas)

Comment: The default plot engine for pandas is matplotlib. seaborn is a high-level api for matplotlib. When you plot with either, you're using matplotlib.

Comment: Sure, with some adjustment you could get it very close. What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempts? Have you checked the available configurations in the [matplotlib documentation and examples](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/boxplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-boxplot-py)?