# How to change the linestyle of whiskers in pandas boxplots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot, linestyle

Is there a way to change the linestyle of the whiskers in pandas boxplots to '-'? Default seems to be '--'.

I have tried:

```
color = dict(boxes='black', whiskers='black', medians='red', caps='black')
styles=dict(whiskers='-')
bp = df.plot.box(color=color, style=styles)
```

However, while the colors turn out the way I want, the style input does not seem to affect the plot at all.

[Here is an example. I always get dashed lines for my whiskers, but would like solid lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbuq8.png)

I have also tried

```
boxprops = dict(linewidth=1.0, color='black')
whiskerprops = dict(linestyle='-',linewidth=1.0, color='black')
plt.figure()
df.boxplot(boxprops=boxprops, whiskerprops=whiskerprops)
```

Here, df.boxplot does not take the inputs at all.

This is closely related to
[Pandas boxplot: set color and properties for box, median, mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160956/pandas-boxplot-set-color-and-properties-for-box-median-mean)

Comment: The default is '-'. Your code is working for me. What exactly do you want the style to be?

Comment: So you don't get dashed lines for your whiskers?!

Comment: No. I get dashed lines when I use `linestyle ='--'`

Comment: That is really weird. Are you using bp = df.plot.box(color=color, style=styles) or df.boxplot(boxprops=boxprops, whiskerprops=whiskerprops)?

Comment: The second one. The first one is plotting the style correctly but the `by` parameter is not doing anything, which might be a bug in itself.

Comment: Looks like my issue is a bug - unfixed at the moment - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15079

Comment: Weird. As said, for me the second one, gives me a figure just like if I didn't specify any properties :/ I suppose you've added a plt.figure() before the df.boxplot, as well? (see my edit)

Comment: Restart your notebook or whatever it is your are programming out of.

Comment: Run this code only at the top of your notebook and let me know what you get. `import seaborn as sns
    tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
    tips.boxplot('tip', whiskerprops = dict(linestyle='-',linewidth=4.0, color='black'))`

Comment: Restarting of jupyter did not help. Had to install seaborn first. I now get grey backgrounds and all that, but still dashed lines in my plot. In your tip-plot I do get solid lines. ----> adding the whiskerprops= straight into df.boxplot(whiskerprops=) did the job!!! Funnily, df.boxplot(boxprops=) still does not change the box colors. However using df.plot.box(color=color, whiskerprops=) gives me all I need. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!!!

Comment: Can someone put that as an answer which can be accepted such that the question can be marked as solved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ted Petrou's commments helped:

Put the whiskerprops = dict() directly in to the df.plot.box line:

```
color = dict(boxes='black', whiskers='black', medians='red', caps='black')
bp = df.plot.box(color=color,whiskerprops = dict(linestyle='-',linewidth=1.0
, color='black'))
```

As for df.boxplot(), there seems to be a problem with `by`arguments. Including whiskerprops and boxprops directly into the argument, here, helped as well. However I could still not change the boxes' color! It remains to be the default blue. The following code yields solid-line, black whiskers, however the boxes are blue. Linewidth of boxes can be changed tho!

```
plt.figure()
df.boxplot(boxprops= dict(linewidth=1.0, color='black')
, whiskerprops=dict(linestyle='-',linewidth=1.0, color='black'))
```

If anyone can help with changing boxes colors in df.boxplot(), please do comment. From the pandas documentation I get, that people should rather use df.plot.box anyways tho.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mu, sigma = 0, 1 
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)

df = pd.DataFrame(s)

bPlot = df.boxplot(whiskerprops = dict(linestyle='--'
                           , linewidth=2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have pandas here but it uses matplotlib.  [pyplot.boxplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) returns

> A dictionary mapping each component of the boxplot to a list of the matplotlib.lines.Line2D instances created.

One set of lines is for the whiskers.  You can set the [linestyle property](https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle) for each whisker by accessing it through the dictionary.

```
from pprint import pprint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.8]]
a = plt.boxplot(data)
pprint(a)
for whisker in a['whiskers']:
    whisker.set_linestyle('-.')
    print(whisker.get_linestyle())
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Available linestyles are shown in this [line_styles_reference](https://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/line_styles_reference.html) example.

Comment: thanks. interestingly, changing the styles for 'plt.boxplot()' didn't give any problems. However using pandas, df.boxplot() did not take the by arguments. I might give it a try your way and let you know how it goes!