# boxplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'linestyle'

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I am trying to show box-plot of some Ratings data from a Pandas DataFrame. I want to get meanline shown in Box-plot. When I pass `meanline=True`, the line shows as doted but when I pass parameter `linestyle='-'` or `linestyle='--'` or however in other way it shows an error

```
TypeError: boxplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'linestyle'
```

My code is

```
sns.boxplot(x="rating", data=df, whis=5, color='None', showmeans=True, meanline=True, linestyle='-', linewidth=5)
```

If I remove `color` parameter, it's default color shows that's almost faded blue. But when I pass `color='None'` then it shows box as black and meanline is at least visible then. I have tried a lot of different combinations of parameters to check if it works but in vein.

Now, I want

- Full meanline not doted in black color so that it will be clearly visible

Remember! the main issue is that error with `linestyle` parameter not with the designing of Box.
Hope so I explained it enough

Comment: I think the error is quite self explanatory, there is no `linestyle` parameter in box plot.

Comment: @mozway I know that what it is saying, but when I searched for it on different places, even on stackoverflow, many of the developers used that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit properties of whiskers, fliers, caps, etc. in Seaborn boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36874697/7758804)

Comment: @mozway See Ted Petruo's comment on this question. He said that he used it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46226032/how-to-change-the-linestyle-of-whiskers-in-pandas-boxplots

Comment: From what I read, the used approach is the `xxxprops={'subparam': 'value'}` one. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68898431/16343464) and the linked [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/boxplot.html) and posts for reference. Let us know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As there are many lines in a box plot you need to tell which one you want to customize. Use the `meanprops={'linestyle': '-'}` parameter.

```
sns.boxplot(x="rating", data=df, whis=5, color='None', showmeans=True, meanline=True, meanprops={'linestyle'='-', 'linewidth': 5})
```

Check the documentation on [boxplot customization](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/boxplot.html) for further details.