# Change the colors of outline and median lines of boxplot in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create boxplot from pandas dataframe using matplotlib.

I am able to get the boxplot and change the linewidth of outlines and median lines, but I would like to change all the colors to black. 
I tried several ways as described in [Pandas boxplot: set color and properties for box, median, mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160956/pandas-boxplot-set-color-and-properties-for-box-median-mean) and [Change the facecolor of boxplot in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297093/change-the-facecolor-of-boxplot-in-pandas).

However, none of them worked for my case.

Could someone solve these problems?

**Here are my codes:**

version: python 3.6.5

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import DataFrame, Series
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    df = pd.read_excel("training.xls")

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    boxprops = dict(color="black",linewidth=1.5)
    medianprops = dict(color="black",linewidth=1.5)


    df.boxplot(column=["MEAN"],by="SrcID_Feat",ax=ax,
              boxprops=boxprops,medianprops=medianprops)

    plt.grid(False)
```

**Result**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: You may want to accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way to solve your problem (details which are not relevant for the question are omitted):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
box_plot = ax.boxplot(..., patch_artist=True)
for median in box_plot['medians']:
    median.set_color('black')
```

`median` is an object of type matplotlib.lines.Line2D which exposes a method `set_color` which can be used to set the color of each box.

Answer (score 4):

I found that unless I add the argument `patch_artist=True`, none of the boxprops dictionaries have any effect on the boxplot. For example, when I generated a boxplot where I changed the facecolor to yellow, I had to use the following coding:

```
plt.boxplot(boxplot_data, positions=[1], patch_artist=True, boxprops=dict(facecolor='yellow'), showmeans=True)
```